# GraphAPI send invitation to external/guest user for a specific SharePoint site

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, csom, microsoft-graph, azure-ad-graph-api

**Language:** JavaScript - MSAL library
**Scope:** GraphAPI

Is there a way to send an invitation to an external user thorough GraphAPI that will be valid only for a specific site. Currently I am using  the following code that is sending the invitation:

```
const options = {
    authProvider,
};

const client = Client.init(options);

const invitation = {
  invitedUserEmailAddress: 'yyy@test.com',
  inviteRedirectUrl: 'https://myapp.contoso.com'
};

await client.api('/invitations')
    .post(invitation);
```

Which is giving back an response as:
[image: Invitation response]

The problem is that the `inviteRedeemUrl` is a general URL provided by the GraphAPI. So I don't see a way that I can use the same user in different project and how to invite him/her again?

***Is there a way to make similar call to GraphAPI or even with CSOM that will allow me to invite a user per SharePoint site?***

Any help is appreciated!

Regards, Dimitar